# What can I do using awk that I cannot do in Perl?

Tags: perl, programming-languages, awk

I had read somewhere about one specific feature that is present in `awk` but not in Perl. I have failed in locating it again.

I would appreciate it if anyone here can point it out.

This might be a useless trivia, but I am still curious to know.

Comment: The question would be more interesting in form: What is possible do easier in awk. ;)

Comment: @jm666 feel free to edit

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%2f):

> Remember: the value of [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%2f)  is a string, not a regex. `awk` has to be better for something. :-)

Comment: you can always do `split /regex/ => do {local $/; <>}` so long as your file can fit into memory

Comment: Back in the day I wrote File::Stream (on CPAN) to fix this "issue". :)

Comment: exactly the thing i was looking for.
i will be able to sleep soundly from now on. :)

Answer (score 8):

The awk to perl translator [man page](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/x2p/a2p.html) digs up one thing that Perl can't do:

- Perl does not attempt to emulate the behavior of awk in which nonexistent array elements spring into existence simply by being referenced. (lvalue autovivification)

But in general, Perl is turing complete, it can do everything awk can do. The fact that an awk to perl translator exists should be proof enough :)

Answer (score 4):

[perltrap - Awk Traps](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltrap.html#Awk-Traps) lists several differences between **awk** and **perl**.

See also: [a2p - Awk to Perl translator](http://perldoc.perl.org/a2p.html)

Answer (score -2):

Regular expression subroutines like

```
/regex/ {
         awk code here
}
```

for pattern matching is a feature I miss from awk.

Comment: wow, I totally didn't know you could use if and and in Perl.  Thanks for missing the point.